# Canvas rendering animation slow on safari

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

Recently I am working on a animation draw on canvas. The animation is to create a radical gradient circle and move the outside circle from one side to the opposite. So it looks like the search light effect.

The Html code is

```
<canvas id="intro-canvas"></canvas>
```

The javascript part is:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("intro-canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = $window_w;
canvas.height = $window_h;
var $start = 0;
var $frames = 120;

function intro() {
    (function animloop() {
        $start++;
        if ($start <= $frames) {
            $canvas_timer = requestAnimFrame(animloop);
            render_canvas();
        }
    })();
}

var $xmin = (window.innerWidth - 635) / 2;
var $xmax = $xmin + 635;
var $ymin = (window.innerHeight - 300) / 2;
var $ymax = $ymin + 300;
var centerx = randomIntFromInterval($xmin, $xmax);
var centery = randomIntFromInterval($ymin, $ymax);


var center_disx = randomIntFromInterval(450, 500);
var center_disy = randomIntFromInterval(450, 500);
var xstep = (center_disx + center_disx - 280) / 120;
var ystep = (center_disy  + center_disy - 280) / 120;

if (centerx > window.innerWidth / 2) {
    var centerx2 = centerx + center_disx;
} else {
    var centerx2 = centerx - center_disx;
}

if (centery > window.innerHeight / 2) {
    var centery2 = centery + center_disy;
} else {
    var centery2 = centery - center_disy;
}

var $r1 = randomIntFromInterval(150, 200);
var $r2 = $r1 + randomIntFromInterval(700, 750);

function render_canvas() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, $window_w, $window_h);
    var grd = ctx.createRadialGradient(centerx, centery, $r1, centerx2, centery2, $r2);
    $r2 -= 2;


    if (centerx > window.innerWidth / 2) {
        centerx2 -= (xstep);
    } else {
        centerx2 += (xstep);
    }

    if (centery > window.innerHeight / 2) {
        centery2 -= (ystep);
    } else {
        centery2 += (ystep);
    }

    grd.addColorStop(0, "#531f69");
    grd.addColorStop(0.5, "#8e217d");
    grd.addColorStop(1, "#ffffff");

    ctx.fillStyle = grd;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, $window_w, $window_h);
}

function render_last_canvas() {
    $('#intro > img').animate({
        opacity : 1
    }, 2000);
}

function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}
```

Now the code is working good in chrome but when it comes to safari, the animation becomes very slow. Does anyone have any idea of the performance of canvas radical gradient animation on safari?

Interesting thing is in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lhray/qVLps/, it works fine.

Thanks for any ideas.
BTW, my safari is 7.0.4 and OS is OS X 10.9.3

Comment: You mean the fiddle works fine in Safari? How are we supposed to test your problem then if it is non-existent for other users?

Comment: Yeah, thats is the wired part of my problem. The fiddle works fine in safari, but when it comes to safari itself, the rendering process becomes slow.

Comment: I think the issue is with Apple's WebKit browser engine itself.

Answer (score 1):

I think this issue is inherent to the Apple WebKit browser engine. Somehow chrome browser engine is able to use WebGL more efficient than Safari.
That's the only thing that explains why the fiddle works fine in safari, but when it comes to safari itself, the rendering process becomes slow.

This [article](https://smus.com/canvas-vs-svg-performance/) compares Safari canvas performance.

Here's a related question as well:
[Canvas drawing takes a lot of time on Safari but not on Chrome or FF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45300903/canvas-drawing-takes-a-lot-of-time-on-safari-but-not-on-chrome-or-ff)