# Canvas drawing takes a lot of time on Safari but not on Chrome or FF

Tags: javascript, html, safari, html5-canvas

I am making a kaleidoscope on my website. All it does is take an image (either via Drag & Drop or a default image on load) and copy it 10 times (one for each slice of the kaleidoscope). On mouse move, the rotation and scale of the slices are adjusted to achieve the desired effect.

On Google Chrome and Firefox, it works seamlessly, without any lag. However, on Safari the website is unusable as it is too slow. Am I missing something?

Here is a JSFiddle showing the problem. Please note I already tried replacing setTimeout(update, 1000 / 60) with RequestAnimationFrame, without any improvements.

JSFiddle: [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/L4Leq36d/show/)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    //SCRIPT KALEIDOSCOPE BASE

    var DragDrop, Kaleidoscope, c, dragger, gui, i, image, kaleidoscope, len, onChange, onMouseMoved, options, ref, tr, tx, ty, update,
        bind = function(fn, me){ return function(){ return fn.apply(me, arguments); }; };

    Kaleidoscope = (function() {
        Kaleidoscope.prototype.HALF_PI = Math.PI / 2;

        Kaleidoscope.prototype.TWO_PI = Math.PI * 2;

        var optimal_radius = window.innerHeight;

        if (window.innerWidth > optimal_radius) {
            optimal_radius = window.innerWidth;
        }

        function Kaleidoscope(options1) {
            var key, ref, ref1, val;
            this.options = options1 != null ? options1 : {};
            this.defaults = {
                offsetRotation: 0.0,
                offsetScale: 1.0,
                offsetX: 0.0,
                offsetY: 0.0,
                radius: optimal_radius / 1.4,
                slices: 12,
                zoom: 1.0
            };
            ref = this.defaults;
            for (key in ref) {
                val = ref[key];
                this[key] = val;
            }
            ref1 = this.options;
            for (key in ref1) {
                val = ref1[key];
                this[key] = val;
            }
            if (this.domElement == null) {
                this.domElement = document.getElementById('kaleidoscope');
            }
            if (this.context == null) {
                this.context = this.domElement.getContext('2d');
            }
            if (this.image == null) {
                this.image = document.createElement('img');
            }
        }

        Kaleidoscope.prototype.draw = function() {
            var cx, i, index, ref, results, scale, step;
            this.domElement.width = this.domElement.height = this.radius * 2;
            this.context.fillStyle = this.context.createPattern(this.image, 'repeat');
            scale = this.zoom * (this.radius / Math.min(this.image.width, this.image.height));
            step = this.TWO_PI / this.slices;
            cx = this.image.width / 2;
            results = [];
            for (index = i = 0, ref = this.slices; 0 <= ref ? i <= ref : i >= ref; index = 0 <= ref ? ++i : --i) {
                this.context.save();
                this.context.translate(this.radius, this.radius);
                this.context.rotate(index * step);
                this.context.beginPath();
                this.context.moveTo(-0.5, -0.5);
                this.context.arc(0, 0, this.radius, step * -0.51, step * 0.51);
                this.context.lineTo(0.5, 0.5);
                this.context.closePath();
                this.context.rotate(this.HALF_PI);
                this.context.scale(scale, scale);
                this.context.scale([-1, 1][index % 2], 1);
                this.context.translate(this.offsetX - cx, this.offsetY);
                this.context.rotate(this.offsetRotation);
                this.context.scale(this.offsetScale, this.offsetScale);
                this.context.fill();
                results.push(this.context.restore());
            }
            return results;
        };

        return Kaleidoscope;

    })();

    DragDrop = (function() {
        function DragDrop(callback, context, filter) {
            var disable;
            this.callback = callback;
            this.context = context != null ? context : document;
            this.filter = filter != null ? filter : /^image/i;
            this.onDrop = bind(this.onDrop, this);
            disable = function(event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                return event.preventDefault();
            };
            this.context.addEventListener('dragleave', disable);
            this.context.addEventListener('dragenter', disable);
            this.context.addEventListener('dragover', disable);
            this.context.addEventListener('drop', this.onDrop, false);
        }

        DragDrop.prototype.onDrop = function(event) {
            var file, reader;
            event.stopPropagation();
            event.preventDefault();
            file = event.dataTransfer.files[0];
            if (this.filter.test(file.type)) {
                reader = new FileReader;
                reader.onload = (function(_this) {
                    return function(event) {
                        return typeof _this.callback === "function" ? _this.callback(event.target.result) : void 0;
                    };
                })(this);
                return reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }
        };

        return DragDrop;

    })();

    image = new Image;

    image.onload = (function(_this) {
        return function() {
            return kaleidoscope.draw();
        };
    })(this);

    image.src = 'img/kaleidoscope.jpg';

    kaleidoscope = new Kaleidoscope({
        image: image,
        slices: 10
    });

    kaleidoscope.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';

    kaleidoscope.domElement.style.marginLeft = -kaleidoscope.radius + 'px';

    kaleidoscope.domElement.style.marginTop = -kaleidoscope.radius + 'px';

    kaleidoscope.domElement.style.left = '50%';

    kaleidoscope.domElement.style.top = '50%';

    document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0].appendChild(kaleidoscope.domElement);

    dragger = new DragDrop(function(data) {
        return kaleidoscope.image.src = data;
    });

    tx = kaleidoscope.offsetX;

    ty = kaleidoscope.offsetY;

    tr = kaleidoscope.offsetRotation;

    onMouseMoved = (function(_this) {
        return function(event) {
            var cx, cy, dx, dy, hx, hy;
            cx = window.innerWidth / 10;
            cy = window.innerHeight / 10;
            dx = event.pageX / window.innerWidth;
            dy = event.pageY / window.innerHeight;
            hx = dx - 0.5;
            hy = dy - 0.5;
            tx = hx * kaleidoscope.radius * -2;
            ty = hy * kaleidoscope.radius * 2;
            return tr = Math.atan2(hy, hx);
        };
    })(this);

    window.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMoved, false);

    options = {
        interactive: true,
        ease: 0.1
    };

    (update = (function(_this) {
        return function() {
            var delta, theta;
            if (options.interactive) {
                delta = tr - kaleidoscope.offsetRotation;
                theta = Math.atan2(Math.sin(delta), Math.cos(delta));
                kaleidoscope.offsetX += (tx - kaleidoscope.offsetX) * options.ease;
                kaleidoscope.offsetY += (ty - kaleidoscope.offsetY) * options.ease;
                kaleidoscope.offsetRotation += (theta - kaleidoscope.offsetRotation) * options.ease;
                kaleidoscope.draw();
            }
            return setTimeout(update, 1000 / 60);
        };
    })(this))();

    onChange = (function(_this) {
        return function() {
            kaleidoscope.domElement.style.marginLeft = -kaleidoscope.radius + 'px';
            kaleidoscope.domElement.style.marginTop = -kaleidoscope.radius + 'px';
            options.interactive = false;
            return kaleidoscope.draw();
        };
    })(this);
});
```

From what I saw, the problem occurs only when the canvas is in full screen. If it shows up in a small space, it works seamlessly. However, on my website, it will be fullscreen.

Comment: Make sure that safari has hardware (GPU) accelerated rendering set to on.

Comment: @Blindman67 I tried to enable it via the Debug menu, but it still doesn't improve the framerate.

Comment: You've got some really bad things in there : **don't resize your canvas element at each frame**, this does trigger a reflow of your page, and resets all the properties of your canvas ; don't create a pattern at each frame if it's always the same which will be used ; avoid at maximum `save` and `restore` when you just need to reset the transforms (prefer `setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);`) ; don't use `setTimeout` to make an animation loop, prefer `requestAnimationFrame`. But even with [all this fixed](https://jsfiddle.net/sd1skrj8/4/show/), Safari just can't handle it... Sorry. Tried ; failed.

Comment: Ps : at least with this updated version, my notebook don't think it's an helicopter anymore.

Comment: What is your Safari version? Based on the version it would be easier to find issue and solution.

Comment: Are you testing with Safari on Mac? And the other browsers on other OS?If this is the case, run a test with Safari on Windows, or Chrome on OsX.  I've had similar problems with slow WebGL on Safari, but it just came down to the fact that the Mac Screen had a much high resolution, and thus needs to work with 4 times as many pixels for a full screen.

Comment: I use safari version 10.1.1 both on an iMac and a Macbook Pro Retina, so it might be what @visibleman says. Is there a workaround for this ?

Comment: @Lucio The canvas.width and canvas.height property controls the resolution of the canvas, while the canvas.style.width and canvas.style.height controls the rendered size. I.e. it is possible to set the resolution to half that of the rendered size. This means your draw calls will work with half resolution and then be up scaled  when rendered to screen.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Regarding all the optimisation made to your code, and the fact that on safari it still has a framerate near zero. I tried modifying the picture you use, to reduce the size(jpg quality 60, 30, 10), change image format (png24, png8), change the size of the picture (250x500 instead of 750x1500) and all of those changes changed nothing. Still lagging a lot.

I then tried to find some benchmarks made with Safari Canvas. I found this chart which is showing that the performances from Safari with canvas are not the best.

[image: Rend times, varying drawing area height]

You can see the full benchmark article [here](http://smus.com/canvas-vs-svg-performance/)

I think in the end, even after the optimization made by @Jorge Fuentes González, your code is still rendering slow on Safari then maybe there is a reason and it's in the core of the Webkit engine.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, this is the best answer so far. I'll just have to stick with Safari's Webkit implementation being poorly optimized.

Comment: Yes, sorry to deliver the bad news ! You'll have to put a big modal when a user is on Safari >_<

Comment: Strangely, in 2022, even with M1 Macs, this issue still seems to persist. Why can Chrome use WebGL more efficiently than Apple's own browser on their own platform?

Answer (score 9):

Woah! The main problem you have is that you are drawing a HUGE canvas. You are creating a canvas WAY bigger than the window size. Although part of the canvas is not shown, the calculations to draw on that area are done anyway. You only have to draw the pixels that can be viewed.

Here you can see your actual canvas size: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnfFM.png

With this and @Kaiido tips I created this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Llorx/sd1skrj8/9/

My canvas size: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XU6D4.png

I simply created a canvas filling the viewport and draw inside it increasing the arc radius, being the canvas the one limiting the pixels "viewport", and not the window.

Changed:

```
this.context.arc(0, 0, this.radius, step * -0.51, step * 0.51);
// [...]
kaleidoscope.domElement.style.marginLeft = -kaleidoscope.radius + 'px';
kaleidoscope.domElement.style.marginTop = -kaleidoscope.radius + 'px';
kaleidoscope.domElement.style.left = '50%';
kaleidoscope.domElement.style.top = '50%';
```

for

```
this.context.arc(0, 0, this.radius*1.5, step * -0.51, step * 0.51);
// [...]
kaleidoscope.domElement.style.width = "100vw";
kaleidoscope.domElement.style.height = "100vh";
kaleidoscope.domElement.style.left = 0;
kaleidoscope.domElement.style.top = 0;
```

This can be improved to have an actual circle when screen ratio is not square, and such, but you get the idea: Never make the canvas bigger than needed.

PD: Don't have Safari to test. Tell me if this improves performance.

Comment: Thanks for the improvements, however it is still really slow on Safari when viewed in fullscreen...

Comment: @Lucio Let's see if someone knows something more. I guess that the best you can do now is you stick to CSS and 3d transforms. I don't know the performance of then on Safari though.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting defect, I would remove the css styling on the canvas as @Jorge suggests, then I would render the effect on an off-screen canvas, and then copy the rendered frame to the visible canvas. The DOM renderer will then not need to worry about off-screen clipping.